# Is there a way to strip executable HEADERS (not sections)?

Tags: linker, bootloader, portable-executable

I'm trying to write a system loader for my operating system, but the compiler I'm using LLVM (`clang-cl.exe` and `lld-link.exe`) because my operating system uses PE files as the native executable file type. The problem is, neither LLVM nor MSVC seem to have a way (at least from what I could find) to create a raw binary file (in nasm, for example, you can use the options: `nasm -f bin <...>` to create a "flat" binary file). I do not want to the system loader to be an executable file. I was thinking there might be a way to do this if I could remove the executable *headers*, and keep the sections, but I cannot find a way to do this. Anyone know of a way to strip *headers* from the executable image?

Comment: When you remove the headers and keep the sections, the rest of file wouldn't be a valid PE file.

Comment: @SemihArtan that's my goal: It's not supposed to be a valid PE file. It's supposed to be similar to using the nasm assembler ```nasm -f bin``` to create a raw file of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the headers, but you can't leave the section as is, because sections are also headers. You have to extract the raw data (.text, .bss, .data etc.) specified by the sections from the file, but the machine code in the raw data pointed to by the .text section will not be executable as it is. For example, since addresses in a 32-bit machine code are relative addresses to the image base address, you will need to patch these addresses (There is also something called relocation. You have to handle that). So to summarize, you should directly extract the raw data pointed to by the sections in the file (you won't need anything left behind) and you will have to patch the addresses in the code.